# How to properly Update a Collection<Entity>?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Here's what I tried:

```
    public Collection<User> updateUsers(Collection<User> users) {
    
            Collection<User> usersUpdated = null;
    
                    users.stream()
                    .filter(u -> userRepository.existsById(u.getId()))
                    .forEach(
                            u -> {
                                    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(u.getId());
                                    userRepository.save(user);
                                    usersUpdated.add(userRepository.findById(u.getId()));
                                    logger.debug("Update single " + User.class.getName() + ": " + u);
                            }
                    );
    
            return usersUpdated;
        }
```

The issue is on `userRepository.save(user)` where I'm getting the following:

```
Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.example.model.User'
```

How should I properly update a collection of this entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the 'Inferred type not within its bound' exception, because you're passing an `Optional` to the `save` method, instead of a `User` object.

And I would suggest that you can save the entire collection with one request to the database, using `CrudRepository.saveAll()`, like this:

`userRepository.saveAll(users);`